# Finding highest product of three numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

Given an array of ints, `arrayofints`, find the highest product, `Highestproduct`, you can get from three of the integers. The input array of ints will always have at least three integers.

So I've popped three numbers from `arrayofints` and stuck them in `highestproduct`:

```
Highestproduct = arrayofints[:2]
for item in arrayofints[3:]:
    If min(Highestproduct) < item:
        Highestproduct[highestproduct.index(min(Highestproduct))] = item
```

If `min` of `highestproduct` less than item: Replace the lowest number with the current number.

This would end up with highest product, but apparently there is a better solution. What's wrong with my approach? Would my solution be O(n)?

Comment: I'm not convinced this approach will work.  Take them in order -1, 2, 4, -8

Answer (score 64):

Keep track of the two minimal elements and three maximal elements, the answer should be `min1 * min2 * max1` or `max1 * max2 * max3`.

To get the maximum product of 3 ints we have to choose 3 maximum elements. However there is a catch that we can substitute 2 of the smallest of 3 max elements with the 2 min ints. If both smallest ints are negative their product is positive so `min1 * min2` might be bigger than `max2 * max3` (where `max2` and `max3` are 2 of the smallest of 3 max elements from the array).

This runs in `O(n)` time.

Comment: a minor modification: none of your factors must be 0.

Comment: How did you....even come up with that so fast? Basically I'm struggling to translate the desired outcome into simple math formulas.

Comment: I like how the special case of all negative numbers is still handled properly. Genius.

Comment: we do not care about the 0 factors, if it is one of the min then we just chose max value option, if it is one of the max then we chose min option, then again if 0 is in both min and max options then it must be included, since you have to chose at least 3 ints.

Comment: Note also `heapq.nlargest` and `heapq.nsmallest`.

Comment: If there is zero, just remove it from the list.

Comment: how about taking 3 largest "absolute" values from the array and returning their product?

Comment: That wouldn't work. [-100, -100, -2, 1] would result in -20000. Taking just the absolute values is also not correct since you can't achieve 20000 with three factors from the given array.

Answer (score 2):

There are some catches on this problem, in a list involving both positive and negative int, the largest combination could be the smallest negative, second smallest negative value,largest positive value or largest positive value, second largest positive value and third largest value;

For example, a list of `-5,-1,1,2,3` should return 15, but when there are only negative values in the list, this does Not work, instead of picking the smallest negative integers, the larges combination is actually the three largest negative values, for example: `-5,-4,-3,-2,-1` should return -6. the easy way to code this would be just store the three largest positive values(consider 0 as positive),

Three smallest negative values and three largest negative values as we going through the array, then we try all the combinations of these nine numbers and get the max. this only takes `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a C++ implementation of the program with the running time of O(N):

```
#define size 5
int A[size] = {5,4,5,10,-6};

int highest_product_of_3()
{
    int highest = max(A[0],A[1]);
    int lowest = min(A[0],A[1]);

    int highestProductOf2 = A[0]*A[1];
    int lowestProductOf2 = A[0]*A[1];

    int highestProductOf3 = A[0]*A[1]*A[2];

    for (int i=2;i<size;i++)
    {
        int current = A[i];

        // Max of 3 values:
        //                  highest_product_of_3            OR
        //                  current*highestProductOf2       OR
        //                  current*lowestProductOf2

        highestProductOf3 = max(max(highestProductOf3, current*highestProductOf2),
                                current*lowestProductOf2);

        highestProductOf2 = max(max(highestProductOf2, current*highest),
                                current*lowest);

        lowestProductOf2 = min(min(lowestProductOf2, current*highest),
                                current*lowest);

        highest = max(highest, current);        // update highest

        lowest = min(lowest, current);          // update lowest
    }


    return highestProductOf3;
}
```

Comment: The question is about Python, not C++.

Comment: It doesn't matter what programming language you use, this program illustrates the overall algorithmic approach to solving this problem in O(N) time.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort `arrayofints` first, the worst case running time is `O(n log n)` instead of `O(n)` (i.e. not quite as fast).  But the code is really short.  And what's a little `log n` between friends anyway?

```
def highest_product(list_of_ints):
    if len(list_of_ints) < 3:
        return None
    sorted_ints = sorted(list_of_ints)
    return max(sorted_ints[0] * sorted_ints[1] * sorted_ints[-1], sorted_ints[-3] * sorted_ints[-2] * sorted_ints[-1])
```

(To be clear, sorting removes the need to explicitly keep track of the three highest numbers, and the three lowest -- these are sort-like operations but are cheaper than sorting the entire list.)

Comment: Actually, it looks like this code has a bug in that it doesn't take in account that any of these values could be zero.  I'll leave the fix as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

This method basically works for any number of elements let alone 3. The idea is to sort the array first and then take the product of last and second last elements. This can be implemented in python as:

```
def pr(arr, n):
    n = len(arr)
    arr.sort()
    a = {}

    r = arr[n-1]
    s = arr[n-2]
    return {r, s}

arr = [1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 0]
q = pr(arr, 6)
print(q)
```

This prints out the set of elements whose product is the highest.