# The easiest implementation to find the highest product of 3 integers

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to calculate the highest possible product sum of 3 integers in an array. At the moment my algorithm solves this by using several if statements. The array is sorted and I have already calculated the number of negative integers in the array.

Is there an easier way to solve this?

```
if (nbr_of_negative < 2) {
        // If the number of negatives are lower than 2, the 3 highest positive numbers generate the highest product.
        return array_of_ints[array_of_ints.length-1] * array_of_ints[array_of_ints.length-2] * array_of_ints[array_of_ints.length-3];
    } else {
        // If the number of negatives are 2 or higher, you take the highest number together with the
        // product of the two lowest or the product of the second and third highest number.
        int product_of_two_negative = (array_of_ints[0] * -1) * (array_of_ints[1] * -1);
        int product_of_two_positive = array_of_ints[array_of_ints.length-2] * array_of_ints[array_of_ints.length-3];
        int highest_value = array_of_ints[array_of_ints.length-1];

        if (product_of_two_negative > product_of_two_positive) {
            return product_of_two_negative * highest_value;
        } else {
            return product_of_two_positive * highest_value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is a product sum?

Comment: No need to count the number of negative values and create two cases; just return `highest * max(lowest * 2nd_lowest, 2nd_highest * 3rd_highest)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding highest product of three numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710357/finding-highest-product-of-three-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to check if the highest value is positive. If so I multiply the highest value with the second highest product in the array. Otherwise I will multiply the highest value with the smallest product (to get the highest negative number). To find the highest or smallest values I use [Math.max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int)) and [Math.min](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min(int,%20int)).

```
    Arrays.sort(helpArray);
    int product = 0;
    if(helpArray[helpArray.length-1]>0) //array is sorted in ascending order
         product = helpArray[helpArray.length-1] * Math.max(helpArray[0]*helpArray[1], helpArray[helpArray.length-2] * helpArray[helpArray.length-3]);
    else
        product = helpArray[helpArray.length-1] * Math.min(helpArray[0]*helpArray[1], helpArray[helpArray.length-2] * helpArray[helpArray.length-3]);
```