# In an array of numbers, find the highest product of any of three of them

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an example array of `[-7, 8, -3, 4, -2, -7, 7]`, find the highest product that any of three of those numbers may yield.

Related question for solution of the same problem in Python, that did not get an answer with code: [**Finding highest product of three numbers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710357/finding-highest-product-of-three-numbers).

For the example array provided in the first paragraph, expected result is `392`.

Comment: btw, the answer should be 392 from this `[-7, 8, -3, 4, -2, -7, 7]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greatest product is either `max1 * max2 * max3` or `max1 * min1 * min2`, because multiplying two negative values will give positive one, so:

```js
const highestProduct = arr => {
  const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => b - a); // Descending (from highest to lowest)
  const n = [...sorted.slice(0, 3), ...sorted.slice(-2)]; // [max1, max2, max3, min1, min2]

  return Math.max(n[0] * n[1] * n[2], n[0] * n[3] * n[4]); // Greater of max1 * max2 * max3 and max1 * min1 * min2
}

console.log(highestProduct([-7, 8, -3, 4, -2, -7, 7]));
```

Comment: please do [not use comparison (boolean) values for sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1447675).

Comment: btw, sort mutates the array.

Comment: btw you are the OP yourself, but still you gave a wrong answer?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```js
let arr = [-7, 8, -3, 4, -2, -7, 7];

let op = arr.sort((a,b)=>b-a)
let max1 = op.slice(0,3).reduce((a,b)=>a*b,1);
let max2 = op.slice(-2).reduce((a,b)=>a*b,1)*op[0];
let final = Math.max(max1,max2)

console.log(final);
```